# Matrix ring $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, $\mathbb{C}^2$ with $M_2(\mathbb{C})$-module structure.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

Let $R$ be the matrix ring $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. Let $M = \mathbb{C}^2$ with its natural $R$-module structure (just given by the usual action of $2 \times 2$ matrices on $2$-dimensional vectors).

My questions are: is $M$ a projective $R$-module? An injective $R$-module? Is it free?

Comment: I don't think it is free, because given $x\in\mathbb{C}^2$, you can always build $M\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $M\neq I_2$ and $Mx=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $R$ is any ring and $n \geq 1$, then the evident map $M_n(R) \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} R^n$ which decomposes a matrix into its columns is an isomorphism of left $M_n(R)$-modules. Hence, $R^n$ is a projective left $M_n(R)$-module. It is usually not free. If $R$ is commutative and non-zero (more generally, when $R$ has [IBN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number)), then free $M_n(R)$-modules of rank $k$ have underlying free $R$-modules of rank $n^2 \cdot k$, but $R^n$ is a free $R$-module of rank $n$, and $n^2 \cdot k = n$ is only solvable in the trivial case $n=1$.

If $R$ is a field, then $R^n$ is an injective left $M_n(R)$-module. One reason for this is that the category of left $M_n(R)$-modules is equivalent to the category of left $R$-modules (i.e. $R$ and $M_n(R)$ are Morita equivalent) and since every left $R$-module is injective, which is a purely categorical notion, the same follows for every left $M_n(R)$-module. Of course, this also shows that every left $M_n(R)$-module is projective.

Answer (score 3):

$M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is a semisimple ring, so every module over this ring is projective and injective. Moreover, $\mathbb C^2$ is a simple $M_2(\mathbb{C})$-module, and if it is free it must be isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. In fact, $M_2(\mathbb{C})\simeq \mathbb C^2\oplus\mathbb C^2$, and therefore by taking the ranks we get a contradiction.

Comment: Dear user26857 I guess in the first sentence you mean "semisimple", because this assertion is not true for all simple rings.

Comment: @rschwieb Isn't any simple ring semisimple?

Comment: Certainly not... there are lots of non-Artinian simple rings. But if you don't often use these rings, I can understand how the nomenclature is misleading. If you either change it to "semisimple" or "simple Artinian," for correctness, I think your answer is the most straightforward.

Comment: @rschwieb It seems you are right (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Simple_rings), although some other sources (e.g. http://www.imsc.res.in/~knr/past/RT09/sssrings.pdf) define simple rings as being semisimple plus something. (Anyway, this isn't my favorite topic, so I prefer to trust you and edit the answer as you suggested.)

Comment: Interesting! That is literally the first time I've ever seen an author do that.